# How do I change the letter spacing of my code in JetBrains IDEs?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I know it's just a matter of preferences. But How do you change the letter spacing of your code? WebStorm seems to put little spacings between letters, which is supposed to improve the readability. The thing is, I don't really like the wide letter spacing.

Comment: Change the font in preferences. Seems you need to set a non-monospace font.

Comment: No, @KonstantinAnnikov. He needs a font with better kerning, or an IDE allowing to adjust the letterspacing. A non-monospaced font breaks the columns.

Comment: What I do to adjust the letterspacing is to use DECIMAL numbers for the font size (yeah, subpixels). You need to calibrate that for any font that you'd like to use, cause every font renders differently at 14.0 than 14.1, than 14.2 than 14.3... and so on.

They started to support decimal numbers for the font sizes after a LOT of requesting to change letter spacing.

In vscode it's easier: you got editor's "zoom", "fontSize" params and CSS's "letter-spacing". In Jetbrains we are almost fucked up, it's made in Java. Decimals can save us temporarily.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure there's no setting for this yet because

1. [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-editor-font.html) currently only mention line height- no letter spacing- at least not at the time of this writing.
2. there's a feature-request about it (several, actually), still not completed: [JBR-5247: Allow to change the letterspacing of a font](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-5247/Allow-to-change-the-letterspacing-of-a-font). You can either:

- Try to find a font that's similar to what you want but has thinner characters.
- Wait patiently for the feature-request to get implemented (and please try not to pester the maintainers too much. Better if you can offer to help implement the changes).

Answer (score 0):

Until the feature is made available a workaround is to tweak your favorite font to your desired spacing using [Fontforge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/). Don't expect to get the perfect result on the first go.

Here's a great [tutorial](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Spacing_Metrics_and_Kerning.html#:%7E:text=In%20FontForge%2C%20the%20Metrics%20Window,using%20the%20Ctrl%20%2B%20K%20command.) on how to modify the font.

Generating modified fonts is also explained in detail [here.](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/The_Final_Output_Generating_Font_Files.html)